# Xml schema validation not finding validation errors

Tags: c#, xml, c#-3.0, xsd, xml-parsing

I am trying to validate an Xml file against its schema. 
This is my code:

```
 private readonly List<string> validationErrors = new List<string>();

 public bool TryValidate(string xml, string schemaLocation, ref List<string> errors)
    {          
        var document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml(xml);

        var schemaReader = new XmlTextReader(schemaLocation);

        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings {CloseInput = true};
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += Handler;
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, schemaReader);

        var stringReader = new StringReader(xml);

        using (var validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings))
        {
            while (validatingReader.Read())
            {
            }
        }

        errors = validationErrors;

        return errors.Count == 0;
    }

    private const string Format = "Line: {0}, Position: {1} \"{2}\"";
    private void Handler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Severity != XmlSeverityType.Error)
        {
            return;
        }

        validationErrors.Add(string.Format(Format,
                                           e.Exception.LineNumber,
                                           e.Exception.LinePosition,
                                           e.Exception.Message));

    }
```

The schema has the restriction of the following for BusinessType elements:

```
        <xs:element name="BusinessType">                                              
            <xs:simpleType>                                              
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">                                        
            <xs:maxLength value="15"/>                                               
            <xs:enumeration value="not specified"/>                                                  
            <xs:enumeration value="Sole trader"/>                                                
            <xs:enumeration value="Partnership"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Limited company"/>                                                    
            </xs:restriction>                                        
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element>
```

But the actual Xml instance file contains the element with a zero in it:

```
          <BusinessType>0</BusinessType>
```

Yet when I run the validation code, it passes schema validation (i.e no errors are found)?
Edit - As a test, I also just totally renamed one of the elements and it still didn't generate an error!

Does anyone know why this might be?

Thanks very much

Comment: I tried your sample code and got the expected result: "The 'BusinessType' element is invalid - The value '0' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Enumeration constraint failed."

Comment: Could it be that your validating a different Xml document than you're expecting?

Comment: Hi Filburt, I just made a discovery, if the xml instance file has a  xmlns:ns1="http://ecrtpr.org.uk/nbe.xsd"> in the root element. the validation starts to work again!